# kubernetes ingress predefine domain name?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, infrastructure-as-code

I would like to do something like this:
predefine domain name and reference that definition in all my ingresses, think of the following .yml file

```html
DNS=mydomain.com
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app1.${DNS}
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: app2.${DNS}
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 80
```

Is something like this possible? Does any1 have another ideas? What if I wanted to define that 'DNS' externally in another file?

Also external preprocessor tools are unfortunately not an option because I am thinking about  deployment using continuous delivery with tools like ArgoCD.

The background is that in our company we develop applications for our customers and install them on premise and we are just starting with the whole containerization stuff. And I am thinking about how I can minimize the configuration workload for deployment and instead of manually editing configurations like these for each of our applications I just want to define them once in a central configuration file and then let all of our applications use that file.

Another example for this would be the namespace for all of the kubernetes objects (not just ingress, but also deployments, services, configmaps etc.) which I also don't want to edit multiple times for multiple applications.

Comment: this could be done with some pre rendering. Very basic, [envsubst](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/envsubst.1.html). Or you make it a [helm](https://helm.sh/) chart which is probably more idiomatic.

Comment: Yeah I thought about Helm, as ArgoCD also supports helm charts. But Helm would just move that configuration from the kubernetes yml files to the values.yml file and still be per application.... And I have to worry about up to 10 applications with the number rising.

Comment: well, somewhere you need to set this value. It wont just magically appear. So helm provides an easy way templating this like you show. `--set DNS=foo.bar`. You can make a generic reusable chart that you use for all your apps.

Comment: ok that would be possible if I were to use "helm install" command, but I am not going to that direction, I want to setup a git repo and push all the definition files into that git repo and then use tools like ArgoCD, which automatically pull that files (and changes) and apply them to the kubernetes cluster (infrastructure as code). This is much safer than using kubectl/helm commands because I don't have to give access to engineers to the cluster, only to that git repository.

Comment: you can set values with argo too.  I am pretty sure are ways to use the same chart for all apps.  For example see this https://drake0103.medium.com/deploy-helm-oci-charts-with-argocd-583699c7d739. Other option could be make the chart directory a git submodule. An any case, as already mentioned, you wont get around that you need to set the values somewhere, logically.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments, they brought me another Idea... I could just make symlinks of the Values.yml file in each chart folder to a repository-global Values.yml file... Genious.